# Can't checkout project branch into main CVS Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, cvs

In my current development environment, I have a "main" project in Eclipse that maps to a CVS repository. Within this main project, we might have branched projects, but they're not "projects" in terms of Eclipse, as they still reside within the main Eclipse project I'm developing.

About a month ago, we switched CVS servers. Now, I can't check out new branches into my existing Eclipse project. In the Eclipse dialog, I used to expect the "Parent of target folder" list to contain my main project (which I would navigate through to where the branched folder is located within that main project). However, I can still update/commit to CVS from the main project, so I think the connection was reconfigured fine when we switched CVS servers.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Sorry for not knowing the gritty details of CVS and probably getting some of the terminology incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following quote in some Eclipse help documentation:

> Note: Only folders within non-shared projects or projects shared with the same CVS repository as the selected remote folder are valid targets for the Checkout Into operation. Also, if the target project of the operation is an unshared project, the project will be connected to the CVS repository (i.e. the project will become a shared CVS project) but any pre-existing content will be ignored.

The CVS Root files were configured like:

```
:extssh;username=OMITTED;hostname=cvs.OMITTED.net:/home/cvs
```

Which still worked when performing CVS tasks like updating. However, Eclipse's CVS plugin wasn't able to match it up to my repository connection because the connection string in Eclipse was actually expecting:

```
:extssh:OMITTED@cvs.OMITTED.net:/home/cvs
```

Just ran a mass find and replace in all of my CVS config files so that the "check into existing project" would work.